# Converting XYZ to LAB in matlab ,

Tags: matlab

I am converting XYZ values to Cie LAB, 
following is my code

```
 clc
 clear all
 close all


 X=19.4100;
 Y=28.4100;
 Z=11.5766;

 Xn = 94.811;   % refrence white
 Yn = 100;
 Zn = 107.304;

  if X/Xn >(6/29)^3
     fx = (X/Xn)^1/3;
  else
     fx = (841/108)* (X/Xn) +4/29;
  end

  if Y/Yn >(6/29)^3
     fy = (Y/Yn)^1/3;
  else
     fy = (841/108)* (Y/Yn) +4/29;
  end   
  if Z/Zn >(6/29)^3
     fz = (Z/Zn)^1/3;
  else
     fz = (841/108)* (Z/Zn) +4/29;
  end
%% converting XYZ to Cielab

  L = 116 * fy-16;
  a = 500 *(fx-fy);
  b = 200 *(fy-fz);
```

I have seen it again and again but couldnot find a mistake the correct answer is L = 60.2574 , a = -34.0099 and b = 36.2677
what i obtain using the above code is L = -5.0148 a = -13.2295 b = 11.7476

If anyone can find the error i will be pleased

Comment: If you use Matlabs inbuilt function, it gives the correct answer: `xyz2lab([X Y Z]/255, 'WhitePoint',[Xn,Yn,Zn]/255 )`

Comment: there is no matlab built in function as xyz2lab in matlab

Comment: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/xyz2lab.html Google something before saying anything is a good practise! anyway, you may not have it in your Matlab distribution. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You error is in the exponetials!

do `^(1/3)` not `^1/3`

With the latest you are just dividing `X/Xn` by 3

Comment: Thank you so much. So nice of you

Answer (score 0):

also do not forget to concatanate the values if you like to work with an image, in MATLAB `img_Lab = cat(3,L,a,b);`